# ADB2C password expiration notification

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity

Is there a way for local ADB2C users to receive password expiration notifications to their email?

We are planning to set the DisablePasswordExpiration flag to false, but it's not clear if users will be getting notified that their password is about to expire.

Comment: Hello @Marina,Does the provided answer help for you? Or still facing any issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this is to run a script on all users to set extension_passwordResetOn claim to the current date and time as per this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days).

Then every time the user logs on, get the date. When it's got to (say) 80 days, call a REST API in the custom policy to send an email stating "Password will expire in 10 days".

Comment: What if they don't login for a while?

Comment: You could have a script that runs every week that does that same thing.

Comment: Yes, I agree, should probably do that. We already have a background job in our app that sends password expiration reminders for users stored in the local db. Now we are moving them to B2C. I could probably leverage the same reminder job and query the extensions attribute with Graph API. I guess I cant get password expiration from the user password policy object?

Comment: Anyways, I've got something to try and play with. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, For Local Account users in AzureAD B2C tenant we can set notification for exipring password by applying the password policy.**

***Note: This Password policy won't apply on External Users.***

***Steps to Set password expiration policy.***

> 1. In the Microsoft 365 admin center, go to the Security & privacy tab under Org Settings. If you aren't a global admin, you won't see the
>    Security and privacy option.
> 2. Select Password expiration policy.
> 3. If you don't want users to have to change passwords, uncheck the box next to Set user passwords to expire after a number of days.
> 4. Type how often passwords should expire. Choose a number of days from 14 to 730.
> 5. In the second box type when users are notified that their password will expire, and then select Save. Choose a number of days from 1 to 30.

[image]

Reference from ***[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/set-password-expiration-policy?view=o365-worldwide#set-password-expiration-policy)*** , Please have a look in **Set password expiration policy**

Comment: Where is Microsoft 365 Admin center in this case? All I have is ADB2C in Azure Portal and user flows and policies I can create there.

Comment: Microsoft 365 admin center can manage the application,User and many services accross azure, Use this Link : https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/Settings/SecurityPrivacy

Comment: Is there a link to documentation from MS that it manages AD B2C users? I don't mean to argue, but from what I've read so far the B2C password expiration is set to 90 days when the flag is enabled during user creation  via Graph API.

Comment: Sorry I forget to share the MS Document Link , Now Update in answer Please check.

Comment: Yes You are correct Password expiration days by default is 90 days but you can change this by setting the Password Expiration policy.

Comment: Hmm. Azure B2C and O365 are two different beasts. This is for Azure AD not B2C.

Comment: If your local user is same for AzureAD and AzureAD B2C, it should appliled to them but if you are adding an external users in AzureADB2C that won't apply this policy to them